# Can I check/debug what PHP script called a text file?

Tags: php

I have a PHP app that calls a `.env` text file (which contains various configuration information, like DB name), but I need to call different `.env` files, depending on e.g. session settings. The problem is, I don't know which specific PHP file/script is calling the `.env`.

I have tried all the obvious stuff, like searching for "file_get_contents" and "env", but I haven't succeeded in pinpointing it.

Comment: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv or similar